# Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from String not a valid Long value

Tags: android, kotlin, casting, binance

I have an activity and that activty runs a function inside my Coins class. I am trying to convert the code below to Kotlin and run it.

```
  fun timeRequest() {
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val tickerStatistics = client.get24HrPriceStatistics("NEOETH")
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            println(tickerStatistics.lastPrice)
        }
    }
}
```

But I have an error like below:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Long` from String "0.09700000": not a valid Long value
```

I guess it's about casting issue. Even I try to convert

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Long
```

to

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Float
```

It couldn't changed anything.

`theLastTime` var is long but the error points that line below

```
var theLastTime = client.getCandlestickBars("NEOETH", CandlestickInterval.WEEKLY)[0].openTime
```

The returning type shoul be like below

```
[Candlestick[openTime=1506297600000,open=0.09700000,high=0.12000100,low=0.05500000,close=0.11986900,volume=25709.37000000,closeTime=1506902399999,quoteAssetVolume=2649.80091051,numberOfTrades=2435,takerBuyBaseAssetVolume=10520.59000000,takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume=1101.94985388], ...]
```

You can inspect more [here](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api)

The CandleStick library is below

```
package com.binance.api.client.domain.market;

import com.binance.api.client.constant.BinanceApiConstants;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat.Shape;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder;

@JsonFormat(
    shape = Shape.ARRAY
)
@JsonPropertyOrder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
    ignoreUnknown = true
)
public class Candlestick {
    private Long openTime;
    private String open;
    private String high;
    private String low;
    private String close;
    private String volume;
    private Long closeTime;
    private String quoteAssetVolume;
    private Long numberOfTrades;
    private String takerBuyBaseAssetVolume;
    private String takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume;

    public Candlestick() {
    }

    public Long getOpenTime() {
        return this.openTime;
    }

    public void setOpenTime(Long openTime) {
        this.openTime = openTime;
    }

    public String getOpen() {
        return this.open;
    }

    public void setOpen(String open) {
        this.open = open;
    }

    public String getHigh() {
        return this.high;
    }

    public void setHigh(String high) {
        this.high = high;
    }

    public String getLow() {
        return this.low;
    }

    public void setLow(String low) {
        this.low = low;
    }

    public String getClose() {
        return this.close;
    }

    public void setClose(String close) {
        this.close = close;
    }

    public String getVolume() {
        return this.volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(String volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public Long getCloseTime() {
        return this.closeTime;
    }

    public void setCloseTime(Long closeTime) {
        this.closeTime = closeTime;
    }

    public String getQuoteAssetVolume() {
        return this.quoteAssetVolume;
    }

    public void setQuoteAssetVolume(String quoteAssetVolume) {
        this.quoteAssetVolume = quoteAssetVolume;
    }

    public Long getNumberOfTrades() {
        return this.numberOfTrades;
    }

    public void setNumberOfTrades(Long numberOfTrades) {
        this.numberOfTrades = numberOfTrades;
    }

    public String getTakerBuyBaseAssetVolume() {
        return this.takerBuyBaseAssetVolume;
    }

    public void setTakerBuyBaseAssetVolume(String takerBuyBaseAssetVolume) {
        this.takerBuyBaseAssetVolume = takerBuyBaseAssetVolume;
    }

    public String getTakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume() {
        return this.takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume;
    }

    public void setTakerBuyQuoteAssetVolume(String takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume) {
        this.takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume = takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (new ToStringBuilder(this, BinanceApiConstants.TO_STRING_BUILDER_STYLE)).append("openTime", this.openTime).append("open", this.open).append("high", this.high).append("low", this.low).append("close", this.close).append("volume", this.volume).append("closeTime", this.closeTime).append("quoteAssetVolume", this.quoteAssetVolume).append("numberOfTrades", this.numberOfTrades).append("takerBuyBaseAssetVolume", this.takerBuyBaseAssetVolume).append("takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume", this.takerBuyQuoteAssetVolume).toString();
    }
}
```

How can I get this openTime value without error?

Comment: A `Long` is a long integer value. Long values are in the format: "123L". If you have a decimal it is not a `Long`. So you should use `Double` instead, or consider values that are not Long to be invalid and either throw a custom exception or return a default value (like `0`)

Comment: @Eselfar I tried with double also.But same result unfortunately

Comment: Where does `"0.09700000"` come from?

Comment: @Eselfar i tried other properties too.It's one of them i guess.Inside the Candlestick list.

Comment: @Eselfar open value is 0.09700000 inside the Candlestick list.

Comment: How do you end up with that value when you request `openTime`?

Comment: client.getCandlestickBars("NEOETH", CandlestickInterval.WEEKLY)[0].openTime this code is supposed to do that job.

Comment: @Eselfar Actually I am trying to convert that code to Kotlin
List<Candlestick> candlesticks = client.getCandlestickBars("NEOETH", CandlestickInterval.WEEKLY);
System.out.println(candlesticks);
Even I convert it I have still have that error.

Comment: Is what you provided the exact code you're using? Same question for the return response.

Comment: @Eselfar I couldn't understand what you mean exactly.